# Remove character from the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string, now I want to replace commas between the string.

```
Declare @Query nvarchar(max)
Set @Query = 'Item1,Item2,"Item,Demo,3",New'
```

From the given string I want to remove comma from between double quotes("")

I want result like this

```
'Item1,Item2,ItemDemo3,New'
```

Here this  `"Item,Demo,3"` part now `ItemDemo3`

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use PATINDEX to find a pattern.
Here I have used patindex to find double quote and then used start and length of the desired substring. 
There will be three portions: before, modified desired and after

Then I replaced the comma and made the string again

```
    Declare @Query nvarchar(max) 

    Set @Query = 'Item1,Item2,"Item,Demo,3",New'

    Declare @start int, @len int
    SELECT @start = PATINDEX('%"%"%', @Query) + 1

    select @len=CHARINDEX('"', SUBSTRING(@Query, @start, LEN(@Query))) - 1

    select 
        SUBSTRING(@Query, 1, @start - 2) +
        REPLACE((SUBSTRING(@Query, @start, @len)), ',', '') +
        SUBSTRING(@Query, @start + @len + 1, LEN(@Query))
```

Please let me know whether it works..

Comment: It gives `Item1,Item2,"ItemDemo3",New`. The OP wants `Item1,Item2,ItemDemo3,New`

Comment: Right, it should now be the answer of the question :)